# How to find $y(x)$ from $y'+y=\cos x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How to  find $y(x)$ from this equation?
$$y'+y=\cos x$$

Would I just subtract $y$ and integrate?

Comment: multiply by $e^x,$ an integrating factor.

Answer (score 2):

The integrating factor is $e^{\int {\rm d}x} = e^x$, so you have: $$e^xy' + e^xy = e^x\cos x \implies (e^x y)' = e^x \cos x \implies y = e^{-x} \left(\int e^x\cos x\,{\rm d}x + c\right),$$ with $c \in \Bbb R$. To compute the last integral easily, instead of doing parts twice, you can compute $$\int e^{(1+i)x}\,{\rm d}x$$ and then take the real part.

Comment: you mean $\int e^{(1+i)x} \,dx$

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From your question about "subtract $y$ and integrate" I surmise you probably have not had experience with integration factors.  Still, it is not hopeless: From the fact that if you had $y'+y=0$ instead of $\cos x$ the solution would be $y = Ae^{-x}$, you can see that trying 
$$y(x) = z(x) e^{-x}$$ might pay off.
That quickly gives
$$
z' = e^x \cos x
$$
To integrate $I = \int e^x \cos x \, dx
$ you integrate by parts once to get 
$$I = e^x \cos x + \int e^x \sin x \, dx $$
and again to get 
$$I = e^x \cos x + e^x \sin x - \int e^x \cos x \, dx =  e^x \cos x + e^x \sin x -I$$
Then 
$$z =\frac{e^x}{2} [ \cos x + \sin x ] + C \Longrightarrow \\
y = \frac{1}{2} [ \cos x + \sin x ] + C e^{-x} $$

Answer (score 0):

This is a non conventional approach, you may enjoy:

1. $y'+y=\cos x$

Let $y=\sin t$, then $y'=\cos t$.

We get: $\sin t + \cos t= \cos x$. Since $\cos t = \sqrt {1-(\sin t)^2}.$

2. $\sin t + \sqrt {1-(\sin t)^2}= \cos x. \quad$

From this we derive a quadratic equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ (I leave it to you...)

3. $y^2 - \cos x \times y + \frac{(\cos x)^2-1}{2}=0 $

Replace $\frac{(\cos x)^2-1}{2}=-\frac{(\sin x)^2}{2}$

Get final equation

4. $y^2 - \cos x \times y - \frac{(\sin x)^2}{2}=0 $

I will leave you to solve this equation.